# How to solve the differential equation: $x''\cos t+x'\sin t+x\cos^3(t)=0$ ,$x''\cos t+x'\sin t+x\cos^3(t)=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the differential equation: $x''\cos t+x'\sin t+x\cos^3t=0$ on $\left ( -\frac \pi 2;\frac \pi 2 \right ) $, know that exist two experiences $x_1;x_2$ such that $x_1^2+x_2^2=1$

Could you give me some hints? Thank for helping.

Comment: I like your question very much..Here's a +1.

Comment: Which differential equations $$a(t)x''(t)+b(t)x'(t)+c(t)x(t)=0$$ can you solve? There are *methods* to do so...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's use a change of variable, namely $l = sin(t)$. Let's use the following notation:$$x(l) = x(t)$$ to see the function $x(t)$ through $l$ (i.e. $x(t) = x(sin(l)) = x(l)$)

By chain rule we can say:
$$x'(t) = \frac{dx}{dt} = \frac{dx}{dl}\frac{dl}{dt}=x'(l)cos(t)$$
Also
$$x''(t) = x''(l)(\frac{dl}{dt})^2 + x'(l)\frac{d^2l}{dt^2} = x''(l)cos^2(t) - x'(l)sin(t)$$

Substitute the $1^{st}$ and $2^{nd}$ derivatives in the differential equation, you get

$$x''(l)cos^3(t) -x'(l)sin(t)cos(t) + x'(l)sin(t)cos(t) + x(l)cos^3(t) = 0$$
or
$$x''(l) + x(l) = 0$$
The solutions are known by the canonical trignometric basis, $x(l) = Kcos(l)$ and $x(l) = Ksin(l)$. Your final solutions are 
$$x_1(t) = sin(sin(t))$$ and $$x_2(t) = cos(sin(t))$$